# Can a probe in kubernetes tell the infrastructure that the service has definitely failed?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

If I know for a fact during startup that my service will not work.. Is there anything I can return from one of the probes that will tell Kubernetes to act as if the pod is no longer usable and needs to be restarted?

Right now as far as I understand the only responses are 200-399 which will be handled as "success" and anything else which is regarded as a failure. Are there any other options?

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/

Comment: if a liveness probe fails, kubelet will restart the pod. You want something else to do the exact same thing?

Comment: If your process is positive it's in an unsalvageable state, it can exit itself via some means that's convenient for it (throw an exception, call some sort of native `exit` function, use Go's `panic`).  That will cause it to get restarted, without necessarily involving a probe path.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze. That makes more sense.

Comment: @DavidMaze, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no other ways to detect that except 3 which are described in a document you linked:

1. HTTP check which detects response code.
2. TCP probe which check is the port open or not.
3. Exec which runs script inside your container and check its exit code.

Probably in your case you can use `exec` check and something like a flag file.

For example, your app can create a file "/tmp/iamdead", and you can create a liveness probe like:

```
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - "cat /tmp/iamdead; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then exit 1; fi"
```

Comment: Thanks. Was not asking for other ways. Was just asking if in the case of HTTP probes, there's an error I can return that will recycle. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your process can determine that it's in an unsalvageable state, it doesn't need to wait for a probe to happen; it can just exit on its own, and Kubernetes will restart it.  How exactly to do this depends on your language but usually there is a function called `exit()`, or if your language has exceptions, throwing an exception and not catching it will generally terminate the program.

From a Kubernetes point of view this looks very similar to failing a liveness probe.  The container will terminate and restart; if it does that more than a couple of times, the cluster will start delaying the restarts, with the `CrashLoopBackOff` state.  Leaving yourself a hint by writing a diagnostic message before you exit is helpful, so that `kubectl logs` will explain why the process keeps exiting.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `readinessProbe` in your deployments to check whether your pod is ready to serve the requests or not. 
There are three types of readinessProbes (HTTP, TCP, Exec) and the one which you need for infrastructure should be `exec`, as you can run the command in the shell to test that. Follow the below e.g.:-

```
readinessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - cat
    - /tmp/healthy
  initialDelaySeconds: 5
  periodSeconds: 5
```

Similar way, you should configure the `exec` livensesProbes as well.

```
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - cat
    - /tmp/healthy
  initialDelaySeconds: 5
  periodSeconds: 5
```

> Ref:- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/